# How to build this wooden box

Tags: wood, technique, screws, nails

I am open to all your thoughts and suggestions!

I want to build a wooden box that looks like this (measurements are in inches):
[image]

The idea is to have a 5 boards: floor, ceiling, back, and two walls that protrude 3 inches past the ceiling. There will be no front, so that whatever I keep inside the box will be visible at all times.

The numbers I included are idealized numbers. They do not take into account the thickness of the wood. When I take that into account I will need to increase the height of the right, left and back panels to accommodate that - and just make sure to space the top and bottom boards the proper distance apart.

EDIT: (updated to be a single question)
I am planning on using wood that is somewhere between 1/4 - 1/2 inch thick. What is the best way to fasten these pieces of wood together?

Comment: As your Q covers so much basic ground it tells us that you could do with grounding yourself in some fundamentals, e.g. principles of construction; this research could possibly answer *all* your queries in series or in parallel, such as how/when to use certain joints or fasteners (many solutions to pick from, with no right or wrong choices). There are many many good woodworking guides available for free online, including a number of cornerstone books on Archive.org to help get yourself up to speed. If you want to cut to the chase just look for similar projects to this and simply copy verbatim!

Comment: What's the use case? Do you want it to be fine furniture, or is it utilitarian?

Comment: What will you be using this for?

Answer (score 4):

As a beginner using wood < 1/2" thick, I'd recommend glue as the appropriate method of fastening this project together. A glued joint will end up being *significantly* stronger than the very thin wood you're going to use for this, so any failures will not be in the joints.

You could probably nail it together with very fine tacks, but with minimal, beginner skills, you could easily drive the nail through the face of the board you're nailing into and/or split something.

I will echo Graphus' comments about doing some basic reading/watching to learn more. A couple of my personal favorites, available on public TV (in the US) are *The New Yankee Workshop* and *The Woodwright's Shop*. The former will teach you a lot about quality construction using power tools, and the latter the same but with traditional hand tools. You'll end up using both in your woodworking journey.

There are a bazillion content creators on YouTube. Be cautioned: they're not all good. Some will teach you some *very* bad/dangerous habits. Use common sense!

Comment: This is going to depend a lot on your comfort level and the tools you have available, but I'd consider putting rabbets on the bottoms of both sides, and dadoes on both of the sides where the top will attach.  This will give you more surface to apply glue to, and also enhance the aesthetics.  You can accomplish that either with a table saw or a router.  There are lots of how-to videos online for that.

Comment: Excellent options, in general, @CharlesBurge. However, if the wood is only 1/4" thick, I'd consider it a bit of a challenge to accurately cut dadoes or rabbets, _especially_ for a beginner wood worker. Not sure I'd do those with power tools, either. I'd think hand tools would be more accurate, and that's something a beginner isn't likely to have, either.

Answer (score 0):

I would attempt this in one of two ways given your lack of experience, and likely lack of tools. However, my solutions may require you to purchase a couple of inexpensive items. I would not use 1/4'' wood. Use 1/2'' minimum.

**First Solution - Screws & Glue**
Simply use screws and wood glue to join the pieces together. For the bottom piece, first apply wood glue to the surfaces that will come into contact with each other. Next, align with the front and back faces of the sides and use a clamp to hold the pieces together then add a few screws to secure the piece. Next, mark 3.25'' down on the outer surface of each side. This is where the screws will go. Mark 3'' down on the inside of the sides and this is where the upper edge of the ceiling will be placed. Place glue on the edges of the ceiling that will come into contact with the sides. Now, align the ceiling with inside marks and using a clamp hold the ceiling in place. Using the line drawn on the outsides of the box drill a few pilot holes for the screws. Now drill the screws into those holes. Allow the glue to dry for 1-2 hours before removing the clamps.

**Second Solution - Pucket Screws**
This solution requires a a pocket screw jig like a Kregg Pocket Screw jig. The advantage of this is you can hide the screws if you want a cleaner look with no, or minimal, screws. If you are interested in this let me know and I'll write more. But the jig will cost a little bit as well as the clamps.

Comment: How do you clamp wood together at a 90 angle?

Comment: @Moish, this goes back to my Comment about grounding yourself in basic principles before anything else. Anyone approaching a woodworking project should either already know how they're going to clamp up — *if* that's needed, not all options actually require clamps (although they are often still desirable) — or, be engaged in research which will show them how this might be done.

Comment: I agree with that. This is the research ;). I'm asking

Comment: @Moish, the thing is, StackExchange *isn't* a substitute for your own research. This is clearly outlined in a few places, e.g. one option for downvoting poor questions being **does not show any research effort**, and see the third bullet point [here](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error) in the Help.